# how to restrict access to all .txt file in apache except robots.txt?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze

I am configuring apache2 on debian and would like to allow only robots.txt to be accessed for searching engines, while other .txt files are restricted, I tried to add the followings to .htaccess but no luck:

<Files robots.txt>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow  from All
</Files>

<Files *.txt>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>

Can anyone help or give me some hints? I am new comer to apache, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots\.txt$ [nocase]
RewriteRule \.txt$  -  [forbidden,last]
```

First, make sure the rewrite engine in enabled.

Next, use a negated-match (`!`) to apply a conditional to the `RewriteRule` that excludes any URI's ending in "/robots.txt"

Lastly, if the URI ends in ".txt" then issue a 403 Forbidden.

EDIT: Don't forget the comparison engine is using regex, so you need to escape special characters (ie, `.`)

Comment: Thanks! It's worked!! Fully appreciated for your help!!!